# List bean with stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Can I rewrite the following code using the Java Stream API ???

```
    List<ActionAttributeType> actionAttributeTypes = executeActionRsType.getBody().getActionAttributes();
    for (ActionAttributeType actionAttributeType : actionAttributeTypes) {
        if (actionAttributeType.getAttributeCode().equals("CONTRACTID")) {
            remoteBankingContractId = actionAttributeType.getAttributeValue();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can. And you can figure out yourself, how.

Comment: have a look at the steam methods `filter()` and `findFirst()`. Write some code and see what you get. If you have any problems ask

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to help you:

```
remoteBankingContractId = executeActionRsType.getBody().getActionAttributes().stream().filter(e -> "CONTRACTID".equals(e.getAttributeCode())).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Or get an `Optional` for your variable type:

```
Optional<TypeOfYourVariable> remoteBankingContractId = executeActionRsType.getBody().getActionAttributes().stream().filter(e -> "CONTRACTID".equals(e.getAttributeCode())).findFirst();
```